# Error while installing application written by me on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, logcat

When I try to launch apk file on my S3, LogCat in Eclipse shows me those errors:

---

```
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967): Static storage paths aren't available from AID_SYSTEM
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967): java.lang.Throwable
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.os.Environment.throwIfSystem(Environment.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpReceiver.onReceive(MtpReceiver.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
09-28 16:56:59.020: A/Environment(1967):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error only occurs on Android 4.2.2, android.os.Environment:

```
private static void throwIfSystem()
{
    if (Process.myUid() == Process.SYSTEM_UID)
    {
        Log.wtf(TAG,
                "Static storage paths aren't available from AID_SYSTEM",
                new Throwable());
    }
}

public static File getExternalStorageDirectory()
{
    throwIfSystem();
    return sCurrentUser.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

I have developed an app that need the system permission,so I must declare android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml and signed my application with the platform.x509.pem, platform.pk8 of the related ROM,and then I write to the external storage,the error happens.

But I'm confused that maybe you run your application signed with the  platform.x509.pem, platform.pk8 file of the Galaxy S3 ?

Because my app only run in the customized android pad with Android 4.2.2 ,so the Android framework engineer remove the throwIfSystem() method and modify the SD card write permission of my app.

// Android Simulator

d---rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          1970-01-01 00:00 sdcard

// Android Customized Pad

drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2014-09-01 19:07 sdcard

NOTE:except Android 4.2.2 ,the other Android version (except Android 4.4.2),don't have the error above,but like the same situation of my app.the offical Android system will not permit that the app with declaration of android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml and signed with the platform.x509.pem, platform.pk8 of the related ROM write into the SD card.the system will remind you permission denied.Maybe this is one security mechanism of the Android system.But when I test my app on Android official simulator on Android 4.4.2, it runs OK, I don't know why.

Maybe your situation is not the same as mine.But wish some help for you! If you can read Chinese , you can read this article in my personal blog. It tells more about the error above.

http://www.ifeegoo.com/android-debug-static-storage-paths-are-not-available-from-aid-system-error-analysis-and-solution.html

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using a static field where you shouldn't. Try to follow it back to where you think the problem might lay as each line is where the error originated. It works from the bottom up in this case. It looks like you had a throw exception. So if you have a static field in a throwable event, that is most likely your cause. It's too hard to tell without the source code